# Working out if inodes are responsible for low disk space

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I am running out of disk space on my CENTOS 7.9 server.

When I type the command

```
 sudo df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        436G  405G  9.0G  98% /
```

When I type the command

```
sudo df -i
Filesystem       Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs        8209156     448  8208708    1% /dev
tmpfs           8216177     265  8215912    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           8216177     976  8215201    1% /run
tmpfs           8216177      16  8216161    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2       29089792 3991332 25098460   14% /
/dev/loop1          658     658        0  100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/19457
/dev/loop0        11995   11995        0  100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1974
/dev/loop2         7578    7578        0  100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/certbot/3024
/dev/md1          65408     370    65038    1% /boot
/dev/nvme2n1   62513152 1641319 60871833    3% /opt
tmpfs           8216177      12  8216165    1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           8216177      26  8216151    1% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           8216177      17  8216160    1% /run/user/1006
/dev/loop3        11991   11991        0  100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/2015
tmpfs           8216177       4  8216173    1% /run/user/1007
tmpfs           8216177       9  8216168    1% /run/user/1004
```

I see that the inode usage is 14% on md2.

Can I conclude from this output that the low free disk space is not due to the inodes running out?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: inodes on a filesystem have little or no impact on memory usage, whether the fs is at 1%, 14%, or 99% inode usage.  Open files can use possibly-significant amounts of RAM, but not just inodes that happen to be on a filesystem.  If your RAM is low, it's because of programs running and their data.  Also disk caching performed by the kernel (but that's dynamic and will be freed up when a program needs it)

Comment: Note that in conventional jargon "memory" is used for RAM memory (usage of which you'd check with for example the `free` command) where `df` checks for disk space usage. - But your conclusion that you're not running out of inodes is correct.  `df` shows your root partition is nearly full and you're running out of available disk space there. That is usually caused simply by the  amount  of the  data that is stored, but won't have impact om the amount of RAM memory that your system uses.

Comment: thanks HBruijn cas. Yeah I was sloppy with the term memory. I mean disk space. I have corrected the description.

Comment: I thought it was odd you were talking about low memory without showing output from `free`.   Anyway, inodes and storage space are only tangentially related - it's entirely possible to have a disk full situation with only a handful of inodes used (extreme example: 1 huge file in the root of the fs using the entire filesystem's storage capacity). Similarly, if you have lots of small files, it's possible to run out of inodes when you have a lot of disk space left.  In simple terms, inodes limit the *number* of files, dirs, etc on a filesystem, while disk space is a limit on their total *size*.

Comment: Running out of storage space is far more common than running out of inodes.  To run out of inodes you need to have **a lot** of tiny files.  Most filesystems are created with a reasonable number of inodes proportionate to their size (and some, like ext4 with `tune2fs -I` allow you to change the number of inodes without reformatting - although, IMO, it's probably better to backup, reformat with more inodes, and restore).  BTW, some filesystems (e.g. ZFS) don't even really have inodes in the traditional sense, they dynamically allocate file metadata as needed (effectively unlimited inodes).

Comment: Thanks @cas . Your comments are really helpful and assist me in judging the situation that I have.

Answer (score 1):

If it's `df` you're looking at, it's disk space you mean, not memory. Similarly, if it's `df` you're looking at, it's not inode usage that's the problem, but data space, since that's what `df` shows. Inode usage is shown by  `df -i`.

The reason there's a separate output for inode usage is that on ext[234]-style filesystems, the space for inodes is allocated statically when the filesystem is created. All space allocated for them is already accounted for in what `df` shows (either by being "used", or just not being included in the full size in the first place).

Comment: thanks @ilkkachu . I do have a disk space problem and I have used df -I to give inode usage as I understand that inode usage nearing it's limits could have the system look like it is running out of disk space, when in reality you are running out of inodes

Comment: @stackQA, as I recall the error message you get when creating a file fails is the same regardless of if it's about being out of data space or being out of inodes. But it doesn't look like you're out of space just yet, and at least you didn't say you got the error, just that you're runn*ing* out of space. Or did I misread that? If creating new files already fails (with 9 out of 436 G left), you might want to check into the thing about reserved space on ext[234].